# Observers are not triggering in REST API

Tags: magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, sales

We have developed an website in Magento EE using REST API. From User registration to Order place , we have exposed as REST API.

In that we have used Amasty Special promotion pro extension for Discounts. When a cart level discount is applying , salesrule_validate_process event is triggering from the SalesRule Module. But Discounts (created by the Amasty extension) is not applying ?

Can anyone let me know what will be the issue

Answer (score 1):

In magento 1X, for "add to cart" , Checkout OR Discount.you have to use SOAP V1 Or SOAP V2 [SOAP](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cartProduct.html). Using REST API not Created a cart.

In magento 2X ,Now it available in [REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/rest_endpoints.html)

Comment: Hi Hitesh, Thanks for your information. But when apply discount using theme approach all observers are working. Is there any other way to trigger Amasty observer in The SalesRule module while using REST API approach.